# Leaflet JSON WFS Layer does not appear on map

Tags: json, leaflet, geoserver, wms

Hello I am facing the problem that when I try to add a JSON file with the Geometry type 'Point', the Layer does not show up on my map.
I already added a WMS layer to my map and this works fine for me.
I can also see that my javascript code loads the JSON correctly and shows it in my console as I requested in my code. Hope anyone can help me with that?

Here is my JavaScript code in my html file:

```
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.28, 7.33], 8);

    var nrwTopo = L.tileLayer.wms('http://www.wms.nrw.de/geobasis/wms_nw_dtk?', {
        layers: 'WMS_NW_DTK',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true
    }).addTo(mymap);

    var myLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(mymap);


    var hospitals = $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Assignment11:hospitals&outputFormat=json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: handleJson
    });

    function handleJson(data) {
        console.log(data); 
        myLayer.addData(data).addTo(mymap);

}


</script>
```

Comment: Try to create the layer in the `handleJson` `myLayer = L.geoJSON(data).addTo(mymap);`

Comment: You're adding `myLayer` to the map twice - I don't suppose that's part of the problem, though. What happens if you temporarily use some static GeoJSON data instead of the ajax call?

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213023/use-geoserver-geojson-in-leaflet

Comment: I got it working now. But had nothing to do with CORS. But I am still facing the problem that i dont know how to calculate the nearest marker when i click on the map